# How to get tweets from a user using any python library?

Tags: python, twitter

I'm using [twitter python tools](http://mike.verdone.ca/twitter/) for extracting twitter information. And I'm lost when it comes to a the very simple task of getting tweets from a user.

```
search_results = twitter_api.search.tweets(q="", user="daguilaraguilar", count=10)
tweets = search_results['statuses']

for tweet in tweets:
    print tweet['text']
```

But I'm getting this error message at last of HTTP 400 response:

> `details: {"errors":[{"code":25,"message":"Query parameters are missing."}]}`

Answer (score 1):

You did not define your query. According to the [twitter api](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/search), it is required. Looking at the docs for the python api wrapper, I see these steps for getting the tweets of a specific user. You can probably define a since variable also according to the twitter api:

```
# Get your "home" timeline
t.statuses.home_timeline()

# Get a particular friend's timeline
t.statuses.friends_timeline(id="billybob")
```

Comment: I actually tried those two lines and I got:

`details: {"errors":[{"message":"Sorry, that page does not exist","code":34}]}`

Comment: just grabbed this package and tested it and got this: Twitter sent status 404 for URL: 1.1/statuses/friends_timeline/billybob.json   - looks like the package is out of date

Comment: try the [twitter-python](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-twitter/1.1) package instead

Comment: or look at this answer for running your own: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15628535/how-can-i-retrieve-all-tweets-and-attributes-for-a-given-user-using-python?rq=1

Comment: Thanks' I'll check it out. By the way, have you developed for Twitter API in any other language?