# Getting whole user timeline of a Twitter user

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

I want to get the all of a user tweets from one Twitter user and so far this is what I came up with:

```
import twitter
import json
import sys
import tweepy 
from tweepy.auth import OAuthHandler


CONSUMER_KEY = ''
CONSUMER_SECRET= ''
OAUTH_TOKEN=''
OAUTH_TOKEN_SECRET = ''

auth = twitter.OAuth(OAUTH_TOKEN,OAUTH_TOKEN_SECRET,CONSUMER_KEY,CONSUMER_SECRET)


twitter_api =twitter.Twitter(auth=auth)

print twitter_api

statuses = twitter_api.statuses.user_timeline(screen_name='@realDonaldTrump')
print [status['text'] for status in statuses]
```

Please ignore the unnecessary imports. One problem is that this only gets a user's recent tweets (or the first 20 tweets). Is it possible to get all of a users tweet? To my knowledge, the GEt_user_timeline (?) only allows a limit of 3200. Is there a way to get at least 3200 tweets? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I retrieve all Tweets and attributes for a given user using Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15628535/how-can-i-retrieve-all-tweets-and-attributes-for-a-given-user-using-python)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

There's a few issues with your code, including some superfluous imports. Particularly, you don't need to `import twitter` and `import tweepy` - `tweepy` can handle everything you need. The particular issue you are running into is one of pagination, which can be handled in `tweepy` using a [`Cursor`](http://docs.tweepy.org/en/v3.5.0/cursor_tutorial.html) object like so:

```
import tweepy

# Consumer keys and access tokens, used for OAuth
consumer_key = ''
consumer_secret = ''
access_token = ''
access_token_secret = ''

# OAuth process, using the keys and tokens
auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)

# Creation of the actual interface, using authentication
api = tweepy.API(auth)

for status in tweepy.Cursor(api.user_timeline, screen_name='@realDonaldTrump', tweet_mode="extended").items():
    print(status.full_text)
```

Comment: What does the .items() addition at the end here do out of interest?

Comment: @CuriousStudent it returns the items returned by the cursor, as opposed to `.pages()` returning the pages of items.

Comment: @asongtoruin Thanks for sharing, but I've used your code and sometimes it returns 160 tweets, other times 220 tweets. Do you know what can be the reason of it?

Comment: @AlexanderRyhlitsky Rate limiting possibly.