# tweepy api.user_timeline: count limited to 200

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

seems that with tweepy I can get only 200 tweets using user_timeline method.

```
class Twitter_User():
    def __init__(self,id,count=200):
        self.id = id
        self.count = count
        self.data = None
    def get_tweets(self):
        store_tweets = api.user_timeline(self.id, count=self.count)
        simple_list = []
        for status in store_tweets:
            array = [status._json["text"].strip(), status._json["favorite_count"], status._json["created_at"],status._json["retweet_count"],[h["text"] for h in status._json["entities"]["hashtags"]]]
            simple_list.append(array)
        self.data = pd.DataFrame(simple_list, columns=["Text", "Like", "Created at","Retweet","Hashtags"])
        self.data = self.data[~self.data["Text"].str.startswith('RT')]
        return self.data
    def __repr__(self):
        id = api.get_user(self.id)
        return id.screen_name
```

If I put as self.count a number bigger than 200, I always will get a dataframe with 200 rows, instead if I put a smaller number, I get the correct amount of rows. I don't know, there is a limit or I have to use some other method?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can only get a maximum of 200 tweets in one request. However, you can make successive requests for older tweets. The maximum number of tweets that you can get in a timeline is 3200. The reference is [here](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/timelines/api-reference/get-statuses-user_timeline).

You can do this with tweepy but you will need to tweepy's Cursor get these successive pages of tweets. Look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42225364/getting-whole-user-timeline-of-a-twitter-user) to get you started.

Answer (score 3):

To get more then 200, you need to use the `cursor` on `user_timeline` and then iterate over the pages.

```
import tweepy

# Consumer keys and access tokens, used for OAuth
consumer_key = ''
consumer_secret = ''
access_token = ''
access_token_secret = ''

# OAuth process, using the keys and tokens
auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)

# Creation of the actual interface, using authentication
api = tweepy.API(auth)

for pages in tweepy.Cursor(api.user_timeline, id='id', count=200).pages():        
   print(pages)
```

Answer (score 2):

According to the [Twitter API docs](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/timelines/api-reference/get-statuses-user_timeline) the most records you can retrieve from `/statuses/user_timeline/` is 200

From the definition of the count parameter:

> Specifies the number of Tweets to try and retrieve, up to a maximum of 200 per distinct request. The value of count is best thought of as a limit to the number of Tweets to return because suspended or deleted content is removed after the count has been applied. We include retweets in the count, even if include_rts is not supplied. It is recommended you always send include_rts=1 when using this API method.

And from the [tweepy source code](https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy/blob/master/tweepy/api.py#L114) in api.py line 114:

```
@property
def user_timeline(self):
    """ :reference: https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/statuses/user_timeline
        :allowed_param:'id', 'user_id', 'screen_name', 'since_id', 'max_id', 'count', 'include_rts'
    """
    return bind_api(
        api=self,
        path='/statuses/user_timeline.json',
        payload_type='status', payload_list=True,
        allowed_param=['id', 'user_id', 'screen_name', 'since_id',
                       'max_id', 'count', 'include_rts']
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

**Use tweepy cursor,
#MuniLima is the tweeter account,
#The list which are empty initially, they start with the For loop. to store tweeter values:'create_at','favourite_count','text'**

```
tweeteo=[]
likes=[]
time = []
for tuit in tweepy.Cursor(api.user_timeline,screen_name='MuniLima').items(2870):
    time.append(tuit.created_at)
    likes.append(tuit.favorite_count)
    tweeteo.append(tuit.text)
```