# Tweepy, Twitter Rest API user_timeline doesn't return any tweet

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy, twitterapi-python

I am using tweepy for communicating with the twitter API using python.

I am trying to get a users latest tweet using `api.user_timeline(id = user_id, exclude_replies=True, count = 1)[0]`

But sometimes this returns 0 tweets and sometimes it works thats why I don't know what could be the problem.

Why does this happen?

Comment: I faced the same problem using @realDonaldTrump and exactly the code from this example https://stackoverflow.com/a/42225674/4862360