# Twitter pagination per page limit in downloading user profile Tweets

Tags: python, twitter, pagination, tweepy

Here is the code I am using from [this link](https://towardsdatascience.com/tweepy-for-beginners-24baf21f2c25). I have updated the original code as I need the full `.json` object. But I am having a problem with pagination as I am not getting the full 3200 Tweets.

```
  api = tweepy.API(auth, parser=tweepy.parsers.JSONParser(),wait_on_rate_limit=True)
  jsonFile = open(path+filname+'.json', "a+",encoding='utf-8')
  page=1
  max_pages=3200
  result_limit=2
  last_tweet_id=False
  while page <= max_pages:
              if last_tweet_id:
                  tweet   =   api.user_timeline(screen_name=user,
                                                      count=result_limit,
                                                      max_id=last_tweet_id - 1,
                                                      tweet_mode = 'extended',
                                                      include_retweets=True
                                                      )        
              else:
                  tweet   =   api.user_timeline(screen_name=user,
                                                          count=result_limit,
                                                          tweet_mode = 'extended',
                                                          include_retweets=True)
              json_str = json.dumps(tweet, ensure_ascii=False, indent=4)
```

as per author "`result_limit` and `max_pages` are multiplied together to get the number of tweets called."

Then shouldn't I get 6400 Tweets by this definition. But the problem is I am getting 2 Tweets 3200 times. I also updated the values to

```
  max_pages=3200
  result_limit=5000
```

You can say it as a super limit so I should at least get 3200 Tweets. But in this case I got 200 Tweets repeated many times (as I terminated the code).

**I just want 3200 Tweets per user profile, nothing fancy.** Consider that I have 100 users list, so I want that in an efficient way. Currently seems like I am just sending so many requests and wasting time and assets.

Even though I update the code with a smaller value of `max_pages`, I am still not sure what should be that value, **How am I supposed to know that a one-page covers how many Tweets?**

Note: "[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42225364/getting-whole-user-timeline-of-a-twitter-user) is not useful" as it has an error at `.item()` so please don't mark it duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

You don't change `last_tweet_id` after setting it to `False`, so only the code in the `else` block is executing. None of the parameters in that method call change while looping, so you're making the same request and receiving the same response back over and over again.

Also, neither `page` nor `max_pages` changes within your loop, so this will loop infinitely.

I would recommend looking into using [`tweepy.Cursor`](https://tweepy.readthedocs.io/en/v4.2.0/pagination.html#tweepy.Cursor) instead, as it handles pagination for you.