# Is there a way to return the entire history of a users Tweets via the Twitter API?

Tags: python, twitter, twitterapi-python

Currently doing a project in which it would be helpful to return given some user the entire history of that users tweets.

I have seen the Timeline Endpoint documentation, and noticed that it only supports getting the most recent 3200 tweets for some user.

Is there anything out there that may be better suited for the task I am interested in?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: duplicate of : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42225364/getting-whole-user-timeline-of-a-twitter-user

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Getting whole user timeline of a Twitter user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42225364/getting-whole-user-timeline-of-a-twitter-user)

Comment: Yes, you can use the full archive search access to do it, but you need to be an accredited academic researcher.